# How to loop over async calls using promises

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have an array of values that I want to loop over and pass to an asynchronous call, like so:

```
_.each(ids,function(id){
    doAsync(id);
});
```

I want to wait until all asynchronous calls are complete and `.then()` do something. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: take a look at `q.all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use Promise.all:

```
var promises = [];
_.each(ids,function(id){
    promises.push(doAsync(id));
});
Promise.all(promises).then(...)
```

But of course each `doAsync` has to return a Promise in this case.